# How to use jquery ui slider in react js

Tags: reactjs, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I'm trying to build a ui range slider component in react js using jQuery UI slider, specifically for time range. From the documentation I can apply it to a regular javascript page. I'm finding it difficult to implement it in React.

I already installed jQuery ui to my application, but the classNames and id's are not applied. How can I implement the `slider` in React?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import $ from 'jquery'
import slider from 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/slider'


export default function TimeSlider() {

    return (
        <div>
            <p>
                <label for="amount">Time range:</label>
                <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style={{ border: 0, color: 
                '#f6931f', fontWeight: 'bold' }} />
            </p>

            <div id="slider-range" />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: I have a simple answer but I hope this will help you check this link *https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-ui-slider* Thanks :)